# Download Multiple Images(ThumbNails) in an Activity

Tags: android

I need to download multiple images(thumbnails) in an activity for my gallery application.For that i am spawning single AsyncTask for each Image i.e. say if there are 50 images hence 50 asynctasks.The problem arises when the no of asynctasks increase in number ,resulting in a wierd behaviour .The app doesnot crash whereas just the activity is destroyed

Logcat shows VM problem,any idea plz help??

Answer (score -1):

Instead of spawning 'n' asynctasks for 'n' images, use a single. look into [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview), this should help you